# Time Limit Exceeded in python

Tags: performance, function

Problem: Given an array of numbers nums, in which exactly two elements appear only once and all the other elements appear exactly twice. Find the two elements that appear only once.

Example:

```
Input:  [1,2,1,3,2,5]
Output: [3,5]
```

but in leetcode.com my fuction gives me `" Time Limit Exceeded "`  how can I speed up my function:

```
my_list = [1,2,1,3,2,5]
dif_list =[my_list[i] for i in range(len(my_list)) if (my_list.count(my_list[i]) == 1 )]            
print(dif_list)
```

Comment: Looks like a question to https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    single=set(nums)        
    z=[a for a in nums if not a in single or single.remove(a)]
    return [i for i in nums if not i in z]
```

You can use this Code. I think, this is faster.